# how to start a process by normal user privilege by custom action

Tags: installation, wix

in Win7 or vista, if a admin user install a msi packet created by wix, and in this msi packet, we need to start a process by normal user privilege, how can i do so, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once a process is elevated, there is no way to "de-elevate" it or it's child processes (There are a couple of different techniques that claim to do this, but they all fail in certain configurations).

You need to use [two processes in a bootstrapper configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx#S15).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer elevates only to perform the installation: you get elevation prompt when click Install button in the wizard. The installation then runs with system credentials, whereas UI is still hosted in the non-elevated msiexec process.

Custom actions are started with the current user privileges, without elevation. So all you need to do is to launch your process from a custom action.